# Google API - How can I get the gmail contact details page?

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

My application use google+ sign-up and login system.
When user click on gplus button allows my app to manage his gmail contacts.

After logged in, I can get all the gmail contacts very easily with a simple $.getJSON call.
Google response is a well structured JSON - feed and entries where I can find contacts fullname, email address, mobile number etc.

My problem is to be able to jump to the google details page of a specific contact.
Here my question: Do you know how can I do that?

I mean ... where is the contact unique identifier and how can I make a link that open the google details of that specific contact?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Google+ data API instead. It returns with details of use including id of that user.

Its response is as below:

```
{
  "kind": "plus#person",
  "id": "118051310819094153327",
  "displayName": "Chirag Shah",
  "url": "https://plus.google.com/118051310819094153327",
  "image": {
    "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-XnZDEoiF09Y/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAYCI/7fow4a2UTMU/photo.jpg"
  }
}
```

Now, using that id, you can goto user details page at http://plus.google.com/your_id

for full details, see here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/#data